# How to start a new WebStorm window on a specific location?

Tags: command-line, terminal, webstorm

I've created a WebStorm command-line launcher using Tools -> Create Command-line launcher. However, I would like to open a new WebStorm window (so while I already have one open) through the commandline. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need another window? What are you planing to do with it net? Open another existing project or ...?

Comment: I'm trying to open two related projects at the same time through the commandline

Comment: `webstorm /full/path/to/the/project/folder` (project folder = where `.idea` subfolder (project settings) is located). If there is no project settings in that folder then new empty project will be created there.

Comment: That only works for one project at a time. I want to open two projects separately.

Comment: Then execute similar command **twice**. There is no option to launch multiple projects in one go.

Comment: Yes this does seem to work when webstorm is already running. But not when webstorm is still starting.. That's too bad, but this gives me a start atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can give multiple arguments to webstorm to open, e.g.:

```
wstorm /home/user/project1/ home/user/project2/
```